# Get particular elements from a regex command for mathematical expression

Tags: python, regex

I want to get some patterns in a mathematical expression.

These patterns are of this form : "1.e10" or "1.e7" (where 1.e stands for 10^blabla)
I want not only to recognize these patterns but also make my algorithm to return the numbers (here 10 or 7)

So I've tried this :

```
pattern = re.compile("1.e(\d)*")
pattern.search(my expression)
```

But I don't figure out how to get the numbers

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

regx like this

```
"1\.e(\d*)"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to extract the exponent of the exponential notation, would you please try something like:

```
import re

l = ['1.e10', '1.e7', '2.0E+8', '3.58e-5']   # example inputs

for i in l:
    m = re.search(r'\d\.\d*[eE]([+-]?\d+)', i)
    print(m.group(1))                        # print the exponent
```

Output:

```
10
7
+8
-5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
(?P<main>-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?)(?:[eE](?P<exponent>[+-]?\d+))?
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/AQ1yuX/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -?                       '-' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [eE]                     any character of: 'e', 'E'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [+-]?                    any character of: '+', '-' (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##NY3NCoJAFEb38xR350zqkEkkUc2qfXuVEL3mLOaH6w3q6c2gVt@B78CJb56CL5fFuhiIgVAIxpnvMxOcISk0FtsM1jlksNPba1plUOp9hfk@Ea7jfsJ5FQn1aP1gGUlSIs3t5DrrL7lphlSaY6ObYaOMWrHGa/v98RWDR8@XOs3br6aUSTL4x5WIZD3L2ukHhWccbM9SwRgIHFgPv3SrxLJ8AA):

```py
import re

test_str = '1.e10, 1.e7, 2.0E+8, 3.58e-5'
matches = re.finditer(r'(?P<main>-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?)(?:[eE](?P<exponent>[+-]?\d+))?', test_str)
print([m.groupdict() for m in matches])
```

**Results**: `[{'main': '1.', 'exponent': '10'}, {'main': '1.', 'exponent': '7'}, {'main': '2.0', 'exponent': '+8'}, {'main': '3.58', 'exponent': '-5'}]`